# How to customize icons used by Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook

When you share a link from The Globe and Mail to your Facebook wall, you get a little custom icon (maple leaf) next to the "Like" button, instead of the usual general page icon. Looking at the Facebook page source, you can see that the icon is [stored here](http://photos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/40/126045934076200/app_2_126045934076200_5494.gif).

However, going back to the [Globe and Mail page](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/politics/second-reading/gerald-caplan/the-world-after-911-naomi-klein-prevails-again/article2159689/) and looking at its page source, it's not clear where this icon is actually coming from. At first I thought Facebook was grabbing the site's [favicon.ico](http://beta.images.theglobeandmail.com/images/gam/favicon.ico) or [iPhone icon](http://beta.images.theglobeandmail.com/images/v2/mobile/iphone.icon.png). But if you compare the icons, they are clearly different both in color and in shape, not to mention size.

[image: Icon from Facebook Wall] [image: Favicon of Globe and Mail website] [image: iPhone icon of Globe and Mail website]

Is this something Facebook has done on its own end? Or is this something any webmaster can control for his own website?

[image: Screenshot from Facebook wall]

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the same question on stack overflow since we are facing the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836753/how-to-customize-the-icon-displayed-on-facebook-when-posting-a-url-onto-wall

I'll keep you posted if I get an answer.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?